# Illegal string offset Warning PHP '#type' in VBridgeApp->create()

Tags: php, drupal

I get a strange PHP error after updating my php version to 5.4

This is my function

```
    protected function create() {

//if (VBRIDGE_DEBUG)
//drupal_set_message(__CLASS__ .'::'.__METHOD__);

$path = $this->vbridge_root_path;
$path_vbridge = $path . '/' . VBridge::VBRIDGE_CLASS_PREFIX;
$subclass = $this->getClass();

foreach ($this->_objclass as $objclass) {
  if (!$this->createObj($path, $objclass, $subclass)) {
    $this->createObj($path_vbridge, $objclass);
  }
}

if (self::getStatus()) {
  return false;
}

// Set User Session Qookie
//$this->getUser()->setQookie($this->getQookie());
// Set User Session
$this->getUser()->setSession($this->getSession());
$this->getSession()->setQookie($this->getQookie());
//$this->getUser()->setAuth($this->getAuth());
// Set User Pass
$this->getUser()->setPass($this->getPass());

// Set Auth
$this->setAuthMethods();
$this->setAuthStorages();

//
foreach ($this->getConfig() as $config) {

  if ($config['#type'] == '#class') {
    //createObj($config['#name'], $config['#type'], $config['#class'], $config['#path'], $appData['#config']);
  }
}
return true;
```

}

This is the line that gives

```
    if ($config['#type'] == '#class') {
```

I've looked at similar questions but haven't figured out how to fix this. Any assistance would be helpful.

Edit: Yes, I did put wrong code up last night. I was very tired after trying to tangle with this.

Answer (score 0):

The error message you've posted doesn't match the line of code you say it originates from. You should get a different error for that, specifically to do with only using variables by reference.

Your code should be

```
$accounts = user_load_multiple(array(), array('name' => $login));
$account = array_shift($account);
```

But Drupal already has a helper method for that, so you might as well use it:

```
$account = user_load_by_name($login);
```